# React dapp using same previous account(from ganache) even though changed in metamask

Tags: blockchain, metamask, dapps, ganache, react

I have tried to interact and call functions from ethereum contract deployed at local blockchain ganache in my react dapp. And I am using metamask. But even though I change the account in metamask the app is using the same previous account to interact. I don't know why.

I tried:
resetting metamask
clearing browser cache and cookies
Removing that account from metamask

But nothing worked.

My code for connecting to account is in App.js as:

```
function App() {

  const [state, setState] = useState({
    provider: null,
    signer: null,
    contract: null,
  });
  
  const [account, setAccount] = useState("None");
 
  useEffect(() => {
    const connectWallet = async () => {
      const contractAddress = "";//here i put my contract address
      const contractABI = ContractAbi;
      try {
        const { ethereum } = window;


    if (ethereum) {
      await ethereum.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" });

      window.ethereum.on("chainChanged", () => {
        window.location.reload();
      });

      window.ethereum.on("accountsChanged", async (accounts) => {
        const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider("http://localhost:7545");
        const updatedSigner = provider.getSigner(accounts[0]);
        const updatedContract = new ethers.Contract(
          contractAddress,
          contractABI,
          updatedSigner
        );
        setState({
          provider,
          signer: updatedSigner,
          contract: updatedContract,
        });
       const from = await updatedSigner.getAddress();
        setAccount(from);
        console.log("Account updated:", from);
        localStorage.setItem("currentAccount", from); // Save the account to localStorage
      });

      const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider("http://localhost:7545");
      const signer = provider.getSigner();
      const contract = new ethers.Contract(
        contractAddress,
        contractABI,
        signer
      );
      const from = await signer.getAddress();
      setAccount(from);
      setState({ provider, signer, contract });
      console.log(from, 'currentAccount');

      // Check if there is a currentAccount in localStorage
    const currentAccount = localStorage.getItem("currentAccount");
    if (currentAccount) {
      setAccount(currentAccount);
    }
    } else {
      alert("Please install Metamask");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

connectWallet();
  }, []);
 

return (........
```

I have passed state as prop from App.js to pages to components.

ANY HELP

Comment: Why are you creating your own provider `new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider("http://localhost:7545")` instead of using the metamask one?